# saving mapbox polygon coordinates to .geojson

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

Can the Mapbox GL API get geojson data to external .geojson file?

I use the Mapbox GL API for maps. The user draws the polygon, and send it to contact form in geojson code
example:

```
{   "type": "FeatureCollection",  "features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          27.66357421875,
          48.48748647988415
        ],
        [
          37.79296875,
          48.004625021133904
        ] }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify it a bit? Do you want to export GeoJSON drawn by a user into some file?

Comment: The user draws the polygon on map http://prntscr.com/p78ok6 than this data go to the request form in gejson code. But the problem is I need to get this data in .geojson file

Comment: Well, if I understood correctly then you can just save the generated file on the client-side. Consider this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side